# Discontinuity in integrand while calculating the electric field of a uniformly charged sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, singularities

Suppose you wanted to calculate the electric potential of a uniformly charged sphere with radius $R$ at a point $r$ inside the sphere. In Griffith's EM this is done by integrating $\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_V \frac{\rho}{(r-r')}d \tau$ over the region of the sphere where $\rho$ is the uniform charge density and $d \tau$ is an infinitesimal volume element.

It seems to me that if $r$ was a point in the sphere there would be a discontinuity in the integrand, since $r-r'$ would equal 0 at some point we are integrating over. My question is how come this method is valid when $r$ is inside the sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The volume factor around the problematic point is is $4\pi |r-r'|^2 d(r-r')$ and the $|r-r'|^2$ cancels against the $1/|r-r'|$ to give a finite integrand.

Comment: When integrating using spherical coordinates you would have $r'^2 sin \theta dr d \theta d \phi$. Where do you get $|r-r'|$ from?

Comment: The integrand is rotationally invariant about the problematic point $r'$, so you may as well use $r'$ as the origin when investigating the convergence. The $4\pi$ coes from the integrals over the angles.